# What is the characteristic of a ring with the property that if $mx = my$, then $x = y$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $x,y \in R$ where $R$ is a ring (not necessarily with an identity) and suppose $m$ is a positive integer.   What is the characteristic of a ring with the property that if $mx = my$, then $x = y$?

This is not true if the characteristic divides $m$.

If the characteristic has a factor in common with $m$, then in some rings of integers modulo $n$ this would not be true either for every $x,y$.

So is it only true in characteristic 0 rings?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Is $m$ fixed? If so,  then $mx = my$ implies $x = y$ iff the characteristic is coprime to $m$.

Comment: I clarified it I think.

Comment: Watch out for the ring $\mathbb Z[x]/(mx)$. Here, $mx=0$ but $x \ne 0$; however, the ring has characteristic $0$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Ah, so the characteristic of the ring must be $n>0$ but coprime with $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this property holds and the ring has characteristic $c$, then in particular we must have either $c=0$ or $\gcd(m,c)=1$. Otherwise, let $x = \frac{c}{\gcd(m,c)}a$ for any element $a$ such that $\frac{c}{\gcd(m,c)}a \ne 0$ (this must exist, because $\frac{c}{\gcd(m,c)} < c$), and let $y=0$. Then $my = mx = 0$, but $x \ne y$.

Also, whenever $m = \pm 1$, this property is guaranteed to hold for any ring; when $m=0$, it only holds for the trivial ring.

However, for any other $m$, there are examples of *any* characteristic $c \ne 1$ where it does not hold. For example, take $\mathbb Z[x]/(mx, c)$. Here, $mx=0$ but $x \ne 0$.

In conclusion, given this property, we can limit the characteristic of the ring; however, the characteristic does not help us determine if this property holds.

Comment: What would be sufficient then to be sure the property holds?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of condition you're looking for. Trivially, checking the property for all $x$ and $y$ would be sufficient to be sure it holds :)

Comment: I'm trying to answer something like for which types of rings is the statement true: If $x,y \in R$ and $m$ is a nonzero integer, then $mx=my$ implies $x=y$.  I'm trying to find a sufficient condition for the statement to be true.  But the positive integer case is fine.  I can prove it myself in the case where $m$ is negative once I understand the positive case.

Comment: You can reduce somewhat to "rings where $mx = 0$ implies $x=0$". A sufficient condition is "unital rings with no zero divisors and characteristic not dividing $m$" but that might be too strong for you.

Comment: By unital you just mean with an identity?

Comment: Why no zero divisors?

Comment: The logic is that if $R$ is unital (yes, with an identity) and characteristic not dividing $m$, then $m \in R$. If $mx = my$ but $x \ne y$, then $m$ and $x-y$ are zero divisors, so ruling those out prevents this from happening.

Comment: The sufficient condition that "unital rings with no zero divisors and characteristic not dividing $m$" is too strong in the sense that we could weaken it by having only gcd of $c$ and $m$ equal to $1$ and then that is also now sufficent?

Comment: Those are actually the same. In unital rings with no zero divisors, the characteristic is always prime, so if it does not divide $m$ then the gcd is $1$. No, by "too strong" I meant that there are plenty of rings that have no identity, or that have zero divisors, which also work, I just don't know how to give a nice rule for when they have the property you want.

Comment: It's sufficient to require $R$ have an identity, no zero divisors, and characteristic not dividing m.  That argument I completely understand.  But now I am curious if that is also necessary.  That is, suppose the condition $mx=my \longrightarrow x=y$ holds.  Then must $R$ have an identity, no zero divisors, and characteristic not dividing $m$?

Comment: Right, no zero divisors and a $1$ mean prime characteristic.  No wonder I could not find a counterexample.

Comment: It's definitely not necessary. I don't have good go-to examples of rings without an identity in my head, but $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ has zero divisors - it's just that $m$ isn't one of them, so it still has your property.

Comment: "I don't have good go-to examples of rings without an identity"  Me either :)

Comment: Ah, we have such an $m$ fixed in advance.  So take $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ and $m=5$.  Since $5$ is not a zero divisor in this ring we must have that $x-y$ in $m(x-y)=0$ is also not a zero divisor, so must be zero; hence, property holds.  But $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ has zero divisors such as $2$ and $6$.